# Controller Function is not getting called on ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

### This is my View Code

```
<div ng-controller="signupCtrl">
<ul class="list-group" >
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" ng-model="signupCtrl.firstName">
        </div>
    ...
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <button ng-click="signupCtrl.signupUser()">Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

### Update- This is my Controller Code ##

```
someAppControllers.controller('signupCtrl', [
    '$window', 
    '$scope',     
    'HttpReqHandlerService',     
    '$location', 
    'localStorageService'],
    function($window, $scope, HttpReqHandlerService, 
             $location, localStorageService) { 
        $scope.signupUser=function signupUser() {
        alert("hello");
    }]);
```

The button is not calling signupUser function in my controller

Comment: You have syntax errors. Please check your parantheses. It should be `.controller("signupCtrl", ["$window", "$scope", function ($window, $scope) {...}]);`

Comment: @basilikum : The actual code is:
someAppControllers.controller('signupCtrl', ['$window', '$scope', 'HttpReqHandlerService', '$location', 'localStorageService',
    function($window, $scope, HttpReqHandlerService, $location, localStorageService) {

       $scope.signupUser=function signupUser() {
            alert("hello");

    }]);

I stripped it in order to remove details which are not essential.

Comment: Ok, then in addition, I think you don't need to specify the controller name for every binding in your template. Try `ng-click="signupUser()"`

Comment: Why my question is downvoted ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `$scope.signupUser` instead of `this.signupUser`

Change you code as

```
 someAppControllers.controller('signupCtrl', ['$window', '$scope',
    function ($window, $scope) { // Here you have to define function an pass window and scope
        $scope.signupUser = function signupUser() {
            alert("hello");
        };
    }
 ]);
```

Additionally, You have syntax error.

*HTML*

Instead of

```
<input type="text" ng-model="signupCtrl.firstName">
<button ng-click="signupCtrl.signupUser()">Register</button>
```

Use

```
<input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
<button ng-click="signupUser()">Register</button>
```

Comment: Still not working. I'm sure that controller is getting loaded as well as the signupUser function is getting called when called from controller as well, but signupUser is not getting called on click event of Register buttton.

Comment: @VishwajeetVatharkar, see updated answer. Your controller has syntax error

Answer (score 4):

You've written your markup as though you used the `controller as` syntax. To make it work just change your `ng-controller="signupCtrl"` to `ng-controller="signupCtrl as signupCtrl"`;